# Algorithm Faster than QuickSort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, quicksort, mergesort

I'm a beginner coder and I came up with an algorithm for sorting (DexSort) that typically works much faster than a standard Quicksort.  This is assuming the number of ALL POSSIBLE values in a set/array is less than N^2, where N is the number of items I am trying to sort.  I'm trying to find a way to optimize it so it doesn't necessarily have to depend on ALL POSSIBLE VALUES and just a subset of values that are relevant.

For example....say I have an array of random numbers where array.length = 10 million.  My algorithm is only faster than Quicksort (on average) when the total number of all possible values is less than N^2 (i.e. 10^7  *  10^7 = 10 ^ 14).  Now, say there are 10^14 actual values that can be found in an array. In this instant, my algorithm will run at roughly O(10^14).  Can anyone think of a way to where I could reduce this?

Here is my code in Java:

```
package sort;

import java.util.*;

public class DexSort {

public static Comparable[] dexSort(Comparable[] c, int max){
    //The variable int max is the maximum number of possible values
    //E.g.  If you are trying to sort 7-digit phone numbers, max = Math.pow(10,8) - 1, or 10^8 - 1

    int size = c.length;
    Comparable[] sorted = new Comparable[size];
    int[] array = new int[max+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int val = (int) c[i];
        int count = array[val];
        count++;
        array[val] = count;
    }

    int next = 0;
    while (next < size){
        for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++){
            int count = array[i];
            if (count > 0){
                for (int j = 0; j < count; j++){
                    sorted[next] = i;
                    next++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sorted;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Random r = new Random(7);

    for (double n = 4; n < 8; n++){

        double size = Math.pow(10, n);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Filling array size: 10^" + n);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------\n");

        Comparable[] array = fillArray((int)size, r);   //Create array of random numbers of specified size
        System.out.println("Array filled");         //Tests different array sizes by incrementing a power of 10
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------\n");

        double max = size;  //Arbitrarily set the maximum value possible as the array size
                            //Runtime will depend heavily on max if max>>>> size (See dexSort method)
                            //Overall, runtime will be O(max) when max >>>>> size

        double t0 = System.nanoTime();
        array = dexSort(array, (int) max);
        double tF = System.nanoTime();

        double nanoSecs = tF - t0;
        double secs = nanoSecs/Math.pow(10, 9);

        System.out.println("DEX sort complete");
        System.out.println("It took " + String.format("%.3f", secs) + " seconds to sort an array of size 10^" + n);

        //printArray(array);  //Uncomment this line to print sorted array to console
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------\n\n");
    }
}

public static Comparable[] fillArray(int size, Random r){
    Comparable[] c = new Comparable[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        /*if ((i+1)%10000000 == 0){
            System.out.println(((i+1)/1000000) + " million filled");
        }*/
        c[i] = r.nextInt(size)+1;
    }
    return c;
}


public static void printArray(Comparable[] c){
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
        if (i%10 == 0){
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.print(c[i] + "\t");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort

Comment: The example code looks like counting sort, where array[] holds the counts.If the max value is n^2, you might want to consider using a counting variation of lsd (least significant digit) [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). Radix sort base 256 (8 bit sub-fields) is a popular choice.

Comment: I believe you're right, thanks!

Comment: "For example....say I have an array of random numbers where array.length = 10 million. ... my algorithm will run at roughly O(10^14)."

How could it run faster than quick sort? With N = 10^7 (10 million), run-time complexity of quick sort is roughly O(10^7 log(10^7)) ~ O((10^7) * 7 * log(10) ~ O(23.25 * (10^7)).

Run-time complexity of 0(10^14) for an array of 10^7 elements sounds like bubble sort or insertion sort rather than faster than quick sort.

Comment: Algorithm will run at roughly 10^14 if the range of all possible values is 10^14.  If I'm only looking at a valueset of 10^7, then it will run at a O(2n)
Quicksort will not depend on the range of all possible values I don't believe, since it just uses pivots in the sample.

Comment: Also, I understand what you are saying, but is that math a little off?  

So, O(e7*log(e7)) = O(7e7)